# Simple object-oriented modeling

Tags: java

I have two classes. Food and Meal.

**Food** contains variables for proteins,carbohydrates, fat and calories. It also got getters/setters for these.

**Meal** contains an ArrayList which contains all the food in that particular meal. It also contains variables for total protein, carbohydrates, fat and calories which i get through methods in the same class.

The above is all okey i think, but when i want to introduce a variable to store the amount in gram of each type of food, i can't decide in which class i should put that variable.

Putting it in the Food class feels wrong because i think amount in itself doesnt have anything to do there. It feels more right to have it come to life in the Meal class.

The problem for me at this point is that its easy to just add the amount variable in Food although it feels wrong. At the other side i dont know where to put it in the Meal class, since in that class all the type of food lies in the ArrayList.

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: First try keeping in any of the class and come up with the doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should introduce a third class, `FoodQuantity`:

```
public class FoodQuantity {
    private int grams;
    private Food food;

    // constructor, getters and other methods omitted
}
```

And have a list of instances of that class in your meal:

```
public class Meal {

    private List<FoodQuantity> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    public addFood(Food food, int grams) {
        elements.add(new FoodQuantity(food, grams));
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a third class called ingredient

```
public class Ingredient
{
  Food _food;
  Double _amount;
  public Ingredient(Food food, Double amount)
  {
    this._food = _food;
    this._amount = amount;
  }
}
```

The in meal have an ArrayList of Ingredient, instead of Food